# Why is PDFKit in Ruby on Rails Not Working For Me?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, controller, localhost, pdfkit

I will be brief. I have been trying to teach myself how to use some of the basics of PDFKit in Ruby on Rails. This weblink is all of the steps that I have followed.

http://blog.clecotech.com/2014/08/download-pdfs-in-rails-using-pdfkit-gem.html

I followed everything exactly, as well as installing all of the required gems. Unfortunately, whenever I create the "link_to", the localhost will not display the page. It keeps giving me this error message in red font saying, "We're sorry. Something went wrong." But it does not show me where the error is located.

Comment: Your server console output and logs should have information about what went wrong (called a backtrace) when you see that message.

Comment: Also, I think wickedpdf now has full support for what you're wanting to do. Could look into that

Answer (score 0):

I advise you use [pdfgen](https://github.com/romaimperator/pdfgen) gem, this gem used puppeteer and headless chrome under hood, this is the fastest way do generate pdf in my opinion.

```rb
temp_file = Tempfile.new("test.pdf")
html = ApplicationController.render('pdf_view', layout: false, locals: {})
temp_file << Pdfgen.new(html).launch_options(args: ['--no sandbox']).to_pdf(printBackground: true)
temp_file.close
```

You just render you view into pdf and then get file ready

Comment: What you wrote, is that all I need to do with the pdfgen gem?

Comment: Yep, i think that is better way

Comment: Okay, where do I put this code? In a model? A controller? What?

Comment: At place that you need to generate pdf file. If you generate it in controller - so here. But I advise you to put that heavy operation on some background job, because you can face with timeout problem if you do that in controller

Comment: I'm still not understanding. Where is the place I need to generate the pdf file when using pdfgen? What directory?

Comment: You can put it on the place that you currently use pdfkit

Comment: Which was in the controller.